# Can't work on my project after updating to Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, .net-4.7.2

I recently updated from *Visual Studio 2019* to *Visual Studio 2022*. Thing is, I can't load previously created projects. IDE pops up a message asking for me to either install *.NET Framework 4.7.2* compatibility pack or update the project to *.NET Framework 4.8*

I've already installed *.NET Framework 4.7.2* (as shown below), but it doesn't seem to detect it. The dialog just keeps popping even after rebooting.

Updating the whole thing to 4.8 is out of question since it is a group project where Visual 2019 is still being used.

[image: Screenshot (sorry it is in spanish, I highlighted the important stuff)]

Comment: VS2019 fully supports .NET 4.8, so I don't know where you're getting that from.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you install the optional workload ".NET Framework 4.7.2 Targeting pack" as well as the SDK in case in the Visual Studio 2022 installer:

[image]

Similarly, you could install the 4.8 targeting pack into Visual Studios 2019 on your colleagues machines

Comment: I've tried installing these but I'm still getting the same exact pop-up dialog as before. Could I be doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you share a screenshot and/or logs? Anything in the Output window?

Comment: Of course. Since the solution fails to load, I've still no output window. The error popup is exactly the same as shown in the question.
Care to explain where I can find the logs tho?
https://imgur.com/a/UoIjoCp